# Django "ManagementForm data missing" when rendering 2 formsets with foreignkey

Tags: html, django, rendering, formsets

I am trying to render 2 formsets in 1 view and am getting a

```
u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with
```

error. The webpage is rendering fine and the data does pass the values to the database when I hit submit, but I think I am passing the management form data incorrectly.

I also want to add that I used "https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/" but it did not provide sufficient documentation on passing the management form data. Also, my options and outcome formsets have the same foreignkey. Let me know if you spot any trouble with passing the managementform data, or if there's anything else wrong with the code.

Below is my views.py and html:

views.py

```
def option(request):

if request.method == "POST":

   optionForm = OptionForm(request.POST)
   outcomeForm = OutcomeForm(request.POST)

   if optionForm.is_valid():
      new_option = optionForm.save()
      new_outcome = outcomeForm.save()
      optionInlineFormSet = OptionFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=new_option, prefix='option')
      outcomeInlineFormSet = OutcomeFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=new_outcome, prefix='outcome')

      if optionInlineFormSet.is_valid() and outcomeInlineFormSet.is_valid:
         optionInlineFormSet.save()
         outcomeInlineForSet.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(outcome))

else:
   optionForm = OptionForm()
   outcomeForm = OutcomeForm()
   optionInlineFormSet = OptionFormSet()
   outcomeInlineFormSet = OutcomeFormSet()
return render_to_response("option.html", {'optionForm': optionForm, 'outcomeForm': outcomeForm, 'optionInlineFormSet': optionInlineFormSet, 'outcomeInlineFormSet': outcomeInlineFormSet}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

html:

```
<form class="option_form" action="{% url option %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

{{ optionInlineFormSet.management_form }}
{{ outcomeInlineFormSet.management_form }}
{{ optionForm.as_table }}
{{ outcomeForm.as_table}}

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. You need to prefix the InlineFormsets so that they don't conflict with each other. Here was my change:

```
else:
   optionForm = OptionForm()
   outcomeForm = OutcomeForm()
   optionInlineFormSet = OptionFormSet(prefix='option')
   outcomeInlineFormSet = OutcomeFormSet(prefix='outcome')
```

Comment: When using multiple forms or formset it's better to prefix all forms (or all but one) in case of any conflicting field names. FormSet's are kind of special because they will always have conflicting names when you don't use a prefix.

Comment: what exactly is conflicting about the names? For example, in the above code my formsets are named OptionFormset and OutcomeFormset. I wouldn't think they would conflict with each other.

Comment: Every field in your forms or formsets get a unique name in the html code. This tells your Form or FormSet where to get the right data for the right field. If two fields get the same html name, the Form or FormSet doesn't know where to get it's data. In the case of a FormSet, it always defines the same names for the initial form count and total form count, so without a prefix, two FormSets always collide. If you develop the habit of always using prefixes with two or more forms, you save yourself the trouble of a lot of debugging when you accidentally give two fields the same name.